# Addition of two cells in html table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have written a code. This code takes two inputs from user and adds them and prints them in one cell then takes the same two cells and multiply and prints them in another cell. Here is my code which is working but after this I am trying to take the two results and add them once again this part is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code thanks in advance

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function addition(that){
var sum=0;
$("."+that).each(function(){
if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
sum += parseFloat(this.value);
}
});
return(sum);
}
function multiply(that){
var prdt=1;
$("."+that).each(function(){
if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
prdt *= parseFloat(this.value);
}
});
return(prdt);
}
</script>
    </HEAD>
<BODY>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<td><input  class="a" id="c" type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="99999999999" required/></td>
<td><input class="a" id="b" type="number" name="quantity" min="0" max="99999999999" required/></td>
<td class="z" id="sum">0</td>
<td class="z" id="mul"></td>
<td id="result"></td>
</tr>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".a").each(function(){
$(this).keyup(function(){
x=addition($(this).attr("class"));
$("#sum").html(x);

});
});

$(".a").each(function(){
$(this).keyup(function(){
x=multiply($(this).attr("class"));
$("#mul").html(x);

});
});

$("td.z").each(function(){
$(this).keyup(function(){
x=addition($(this).attr("class"));
$("#result").html(x);

});
});


});


</script>
</table>
</BODY>
</html>
```

Comment: no errors it just doesn't display the value

Comment: can u tell me why the code is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a part of your code and changed it a little. 
Actually, I used the "setInterval" function to feed the #result with the sum of the two previous fields... Have a look:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".a").each(function(){
$(this).keyup(function(){
x=addition($(this).attr("class"));
$("#sum").html(x);

});
});

$(".a").each(function(){
$(this).keyup(function(){
x=multiply($(this).attr("class"));
$("#mul").html(x);

});
});

//    $("td.z").each(function(){
//    $(this).keyup(function(){
//    x=addition($(this).attr("class"));
//    $("#result").html(x);

setInterval(function() {
var z = parseFloat($("#sum").text())+ parseFloat($("#mul").text());
if(!isNaN(z)) {
    $("#result").text(z);
}
}, 500);

});
});


});


</script>
```

FIDDLE HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/1rcuqskj/1/

Hope this works for you!

Comment: thanks a lot could you please explain me how this setInterval() function works and what is this 500 please explain me these two part

Comment: @rajju setInterval() repeats a task at specified time intervals given in milliseconds. In this case, I randomly chose 500 (milliseconds) which means that the tasks are being executed every half second. If you want to change it for example to two seconds, just replace 500 with 2000 and so on...